# Save in a custom controller?

Tags: apex, controller

So right now this will not actually post the Feedback record to the system and instead point to a VS error page, with message attempting to de-reference a null object

What exactly is off here?

```
public with sharing class myControllerTest 
{
    public Feedback_Form__c feedback {get;set;}
    public Account account {get; set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public myControllerTest(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
     Id accountId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('accid');

       feedback = new Feedback_Form__c();
       feedback.Account__c = accountId;
       }

    public Pagereference SubmitRedirect() 
    {
        controller.save();
        PageReference p = new PageReference('/apex/FormThankYou');
        p.setRedirect(true);  
        return p; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never set your variable `controller` in your class:

```
public myControllerTest(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{
    this.controller = controller;
    Id accountId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('accid');
    feedback = new Feedback_Form__c();
    feedback.Account__c = accountId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! This seemed to be the case yes, it will now redirect to the second page after the submit.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.